# Removing duplicates using two columns and a condition on a third column

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, data-cleaning

I have the following data set

```
   A       B         C 
   1      red        No
   2      green      Yes
   1      red        No
   3      red        No
   2      green      No
   1      red        Yes
   4      red        Yes
   2      green      No
   5      green      No
```

So, I want to remove duplicate rows based on columns A and B but keeping those having a value "Yes" on column C. The desired outcome will be:

```
   A       B         C 
   1      red        Yes
   2      green      Yes
   3      red        No
   4      red        Yes
   5      green       No
```

I am looking for an answer in dplyr.
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(A, B) %>% 
  mutate(C = rev(sort(C))) %>% 
  summarise(C = C[1], .groups = "keep")

#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#> # Groups:   A, B [5]
#>       A B     C    
#>   <int> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 red   Yes  
#> 2     2 green Yes  
#> 3     3 red   No   
#> 4     4 red   Yes  
#> 5     5 green No
```

Comment: Thanks! Allan! I edited what I wrote. could you please verify your code now?

Comment: @Alex yes, this input with the same code now matches your desired output

Comment: Thanks! it worked. So, what does (C = rev(sort(C))) do in this case?

Comment: @Alex you get each unique group then sort them in reverse alphabetic order so that "Yes" is first in each group (if it's there). You then just take the first one from each group.

Comment: thanks! so, if it was (1,0) instead of (Yes,No) should I use `arrange` instead of `sort`?